# Hide Detail Row based on Expression Textbox

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, expression, visibility

I have 2 Datasets (dsDetails and dsProjectID)

I have a table using the dsDetails dataset, and an expression for CityCount to lookup a field in dsProjectID.

```
=join(LookUpSet(Fields!cbt_projectid.Value,Fields!cbt_projectid.Value,Fields!CityCount.Value, "dsProjectID"),",")
```

I need to hide the detail row based on the value of the CityCount.  If it is >=2 then hide that record associated. See Below, the report should only show the IMS Number 5192 and NOT 4868.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gCDE.jpg

I have tried making this into a calculated field, but it doesn't allow a lookup, I have tried many calculations to set the visibility expression, but all to no avail.. I know there is an answer, but as I am new to SSRS I cannot figure this one out.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following code hides a row based on sample data:

Data source:

```
select 1 union all
select 1 union all
select 1 union all
select 1 union all
select 2
```

Expression in**(Details)** *Row Groups* 
[image]

```
=iif(Fields!ID.Value>1,FALSE,TRUE)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi BI Dude, I'm sorry, due to me being new to SSRS, I am not sure what you are referring to in the Data Source union...  However, I have tried putting the expression: '=iif(Fields!CityCount.Value, "dsProjectID") > 1, False, True)' but it gives an error because CityCount is not in the "details" dataset and it can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope.